# What is the best format to store test data in a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

In our project we use test data that is stored inside .sql files that we call sometimes to recreate the database with these tests data. In this file, we store the data like this :

```
Insert into Table1 ('col1', 'col2') values ('val1', 'val2');
Insert into Table1 ('col1', 'col2') values ('val3', 'val2');
Insert into Table1 ('col1', 'col2') values ('val4', 'val2');
...
```

The **problem is when we add or remove columns**, we have to go through all the file (in my case, there are many big files) and manually add columns and corresponding values : it's a big pain in the brain.

So I was thinking, how do other store their tests data ? I think rails way, with .yml files (key values pairs) is the good way, but how do you work with it in a non ruby-rails environment ?

For instance in rails :

```
david:
 name: David Heinemeier Hansson
 birthday: 1979-10-15
 profession: Systems development

steve:
 name: Steve Ross Kellock
 birthday: 1974-09-27
 profession: guy with keyboard
```

Comment: I just like creating a seperate test schema in my database. This way I do not have to change my code to make it testable and any change migration from dev to test database should be  a snap.

Comment: How the Rails version is avoiding you to manually add the new columns and data?

Comment: The rails version is better because removing / adding column is as simple as adding a new row in the file ... With Inserts, removing a column is removing the column name and finding its corresponding value in the `VALUES` clause. With a table of 20+ columns, it's kind of mind-exploding.

Comment: I like the idea of a test database, but you would still have to write some SQL for your migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new columns are non-null/required columns in the schema, then I can see the problem in updating the data population sql scripts. However if the new columns are not relevant to the particular test, the corresponding sql file should be able to ignore the schema update.

Another approach might be

- to maintain a test database pre-populated with known values. Create a copy and run your tests against the copy each time. Discard after each test run.
- Every time the schema is updated, do it via migration scripts as in rails.. these can then be run against the test database as well for relatively negligible effort.

Comment: This solution was in the comment. Being familiar with the rails way, I was also thinking of that as a solution. Kind of hoping for another solution, to compare :)